# My Sigma.js chart does not appear on my Node.js webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sigma.js

I am trying to display a simple chart on a webpage using Node.js and Sigma.js.  I do not receive any errors.  Everything appears to work correctly, but the chart does not appear.  Thanks for the help.

Note: I removed unrelated files from this directory tree

```
|-- node_modules
|-- package.json
|-- public
|   |-- css
|   |    `-- style.css
|   `-- javascript
|       |-- sigma-test-bundle.js
|       `-- sigma-test.js
|-- server.js
`-- views
    `-- index.ejs
```

I imported sigma.js using npm.  I created sigma-test-bundle.js using:

```
browserify sigma-test.js -o sigma-test-bundle.js
```

sigma-test.js:

```
const sigma = require('sigma');

console.log("sigma-test.js")

var i,
s,
N = 50,
E = 50,
g = {
  nodes: [],
  edges: []
};

// Generate random nodes:
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    g.nodes.push({
        id: 'n' + i,
        label: 'Article ' + i,
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        size: Math.random(),
        color: '#ec5148'
    });

// Generate random edges
for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
    g.edges.push({
    id: 'connection' + i,
    source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: '#ccb6b6'
});

s = new sigma({ 
    graph: g,
    container: 'container',
    settings: {
        defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
    }
});

//Initialize nodes as a circle
s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(node, i, a) {
  node.x = Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
  node.y = Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
});

console.log('End of sigma-test.js')
```

index.ejs:

```
<head>
    <title>Test File</title>

    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”ie=edge”>

</head>

<body>
        <h1>Test File</h1>
        <h2>Tests basic functionality needed for the project.</h2>

        This text should appear above the sigma chart!

        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src='/javascript/sigma-test-bundle.js'></script>

        This text should appear below the sigma chart!

</body>
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
  console.log("server response");
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

[Webpage and console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcnun.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, just add style:

```
<style> #container { height: 100% } </style>
```

Hope that helps!