# Using sigma.js v2 with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, sigma.js

I'm looking at the examples provided [here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/v2/examples) and I honestly have no idea how to replicate any of this within node.js. I don't know what to do with .ts files. I'm looking at one particular example from the file basic.ts:

```
import erdosRenyi from "graphology-generators/random/erdos-renyi";
import randomLayout from "graphology-layout/random";
import chroma from "chroma-js";

import { getRandomName, globalize } from "./utils";
import Sigma from "../src/sigma";

const container = document.getElementById("container");

const graph = erdosRenyi(UndirectedGraph, { order: 100, probability: 0.2 });
randomLayout.assign(graph);

graph.nodes().forEach((node) => {
  graph.mergeNodeAttributes(node, {
    label: getRandomName(),
    size: Math.max(4, Math.random() * 10),
    color: chroma.random().hex(),
  });
});

const renderer = new Sigma(graph, container);

globalize({ graph, renderer });
```

Where does all this code go exactly within node.js? I tried just saving it as a js file but I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

If I try using the method provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655743/my-sigma-js-chart-does-not-appear-on-my-node-js-webpage) I get the following error from running `browserify sigma-test.js -o sigma-test-bundle.js`:

> ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Clearly I have a surface level understanding of all these different elements, but I'd really love to learn. There just doesn't seem to be any documentation out there to make it a bit easier to start from scratch and the examples clearly assume a higher level of understanding than my own.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `.ts` files are typescript, a typed superset of javascript that needs to be converted to JS before you can run it in a JS interpreter. That should be enough information for you to look up what's necessary for bridge the gap between "having typescript source" and "running javascript in node". Though I would like to point out the sigma website says the current version is 1.2, not 2, and that https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki is probably good starting point. And finally: it's open source, you have question about an unreleased version: time for https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues?

Comment: BTW SigmaJS is a lib to display graph on a browser, so it doesn't work with nodeJS.